# Connection timeout while trying to connect to an RDS Postgres instance

Tags: .net, postgresql, plsql, amazon-rds, npgsql

```
2024-01-11T19:54:53.7699503+09:00 40000374-0003-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] Entity Framework Core "6.0.19" initialized '"DbContextClass"' using provider '"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL":"6.0.8"' with options: "CommandTimeout=15 " (d2805559)
2024-01-11T19:55:09.4702152+09:00 40000374-0003-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database '"my_db"' on server '""'. (5fc3407c)
2024-01-11T19:55:09.5272113+09:00 40000374-0003-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb [INF] A transient exception occurred during execution. The operation will be retried after 0ms."
""System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.Check()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndGetTimeLeft()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndApply(NpgsqlConnector connector)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|195_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" (43386701)
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.Check()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndGetTimeLeft()
   at Npgsql.Util.NpgsqlTimeout.CheckAndApply(NpgsqlConnector connector)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|195_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass33_0`2.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

This is the exception i am receiving during the time out. The interestin fact is that the second attempt to create the connection always succeeded. I am using Npgsql 6.0.8 in a .net6 project.

Any help is appreciated

All first attempt to create the connection is failed. I tried to add a retry count, it always work on second attemt